# Bandwith usage monitor returns excessive number

Tags: c#, network-programming, performancecounter

I've got the following code that is supposed to measure the current download and upload speed. The issue I'm facing is that there are often usages recorded that my network and/or internet connection can't even handle (above my bandwidth).

```
public static IStatistics GetNetworkStatistics(string interfaceName) {
        var networkStats = _interfaces[interfaceName];

        var dataSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", interfaceName);
        var dataReceivedCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", interfaceName);

        float sentSum = 0;
        float receiveSum = 0;

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        while (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000) {
            sentSum += dataSentCounter.NextValue();
            receiveSum += dataReceivedCounter.NextValue();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Download:\t{0} KBytes/s", receiveSum / 1024);
        Console.WriteLine("Upload:\t\t{0} KBytes/s\n", sentSum / 1024);

        networkStats.AddSentData(sentSum);
        networkStats.AddReceivedData(receiveSum);

        return networkStats;
    }
```

Sample output:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see most of these entries indicate a pretty heavily used network, up to an excessive amount of almost 160MB/s. I realize that you can't measure transfer speed with just one record (this is test data, in the actual application I use the mean of the latest 3), but even so: how can I ever receive 160MB in one second. I believe it's safe to say that I must have made an error somewhere, but I can't find where.

One thought I had was that I should keep a counter in the loop to show me how many times the `PerformanceCounter.NextValue()` were accessed (generally between 46 and 48), but in the end I believed this shouldn't matter: in the grand picture I'm still having a too large number for just one second of bandwidth usage. I can't shake the feeling that the performance counter might be the cause though.

Sidenote: the 160MB/s number was recorded the moment I loaded a new youtube video and other (+1000 KB/s) recordings are usually done when I refresh a tab, so it should be a (relative) display of my network usage.

Have I overlooked something in my approach?

Edit:

Upon following @Sam's advice and checking my results against the built-in `perfmon.exe` I noticed that my bursts in bandwith usage generally occur at the same time as those shown in Perfmon, but mine are way larger. I have tried to link the simultaneous bursts and find something in common, but it seems rather random (possibly because Perfmon might combine several results to get their current speed, whereas I'm only using the latest second).

Same goes for the lower numbers: Perfmon usually shows < 10kbps whereas I'm constantly around 50kbps.

[image]

Edit2:

This is the code I used in reference to @Hans' comment

```
var initSent = dataSentCounter.NextValue();
var initReceived = dataReceivedCounter.NextValue();
Thread.Sleep(1000);

sentSum = dataSentCounter.NextValue() - initSent;
receiveSum = dataReceivedCounter.NextValue() - initReceived;
```

Comment: Btw, 1 kilobyte = 1024 bytes, not 1028. So your readings would be more than you're displaying in your pic.

Comment: @Sam: whoops, embarrassing mistake! Thanks for letting me know

Comment: No prob, have you compared your results with the resource monitor or some other network monitoring app, to see if your results are actually real?

Comment: I just checked: `resmon.exe` usually indicates network usage around 20kb/s, but sometimes there are small bursts that go o up to 2MB/s. Most of the time these bursts also translate into a higher usage in my program. I'll edit my post with additional information

Comment: You are just using the counter wrong.  Call NextValue(), wait one second, call NextValue() again.  The difference is the number you are interested in.

Comment: @HansPassant: doing so gives me a lot of `0.xx` values for passive usage, while Perfmon usually stays between 5 and 20kbps. Is this to be expected? The values don't seem too close in general.

Comment: That's normal.  Your Perfmon reading is not.  Pay attention to the scaling it uses.